# Master/Stage branch pushing into different environments on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codestar

Practically I have two different instances that are running stag php app and prod php app and using code start deployment was being done using environment variables in beanstalk but recently everytime change is being pushed the variables delete so basically now I want to have to different branches that push to different instances .

Can anyone assist how to proceed using just code star to it basically has to be on the same pipeline but pushes to Test branch go all the way up to Test Server and not Prod. pushes to Master Branch go all the way to Production Server.

Thank you

Comment: AWS EB allows to control where to push each branch. Check .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

Comment: @NeverBe , how though?

Comment: it's a file in the project's dir. should exists